# How can I have multiple things executed in Liquibase?

Tags: sql, oracle, liquibase, oracle19c

Say I have this:

```sql
--changeset asdf:1 runAlways:false runOnChange:false failOnError:true endDelimiter:"/"
declare
    XXXXX
begin
    DO SOMETHING
end;
/

comment on column my_table.my_col is 'My comment.';
```

This means that it will only execute until the `/` in Liquibase.
How can I execute both?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle only allows a single statement to be executed in each command. This helps to prevent SQL injection.

For example, this comic would not apply in Oracle as the command would error at the `;` when it finds a second statement.

[image: XKCD: Exploits of a Mom]

If you want to have two Oracle statements execute together in a single command then you need to wrap them into a single (composite) statement using an anonymous PL/SQL block (and put any DDL statements in an `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statement):

```sql
BEGIN
  declare
    XXXXX NUMBER;
  begin
    NULL; -- Do something
  end;

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'comment on column my_table.my_col is ''My comment.''';
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

The `endDelimeter` you have provided is `/`.

> This means that it will only execute until the / in Liquibase.

Yes, but that doesn't mean it will not execute the query ahead. It basically indicates the end of the SQL statement. Please have a look at [liquibase docs](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/advanced/enddelimiter-sql-attribute.html)

For both the queries to be executed, you should be ending both the queries with `/` as below:

```
--changeset asdf:1 runAlways:false runOnChange:false failOnError:true endDelimiter:"/"
declare
    XXXXX
begin
    DO SOMETHING
end;
/

comment on column my_table.my_col is 'My comment.';
/
```

Refer the above link for similar examples.

Hope I got your question right.

Comment: I'm not very sure about the semicolons if they should be removed or kept. Please try having them in place and once after removing them. One of them will definitely work. The main issue is the missing `/` at the end of second query.